# Center of mass of 2D region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, computational-geometry

The problem states:
Find the center of mass of a thin plate covering the region between the​ x-axis and the curve $$y=20/x^2, 5 \leq x \leq8$$ if the​ plate's density at a point​ (x,y) is $\delta(x)=2x^2$.
If the density were uniform I would find the center of mass using `RegionCentroid`:
`In[1]:= reg = ImplicitRegion[{5 <= x <= 8, 0 <= y <= 20/x^2}, {x, y}];
RegionCentroid[reg]
Out[1]= {40/3 Log[8/5], 43/160}`
Is there an "easy" way like this to compute the center of mass when the density function is given? I'm trying to avoid setting up integrals manually.
It seems to me that what I need is Geometric Centroid. "http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricCentroid.html" says:

> The centroid is center of mass of a two-dimensional planar lamina or a
>   three-dimensional solid. The mass of a lamina with surface density
>   function $\sigma(x,y)$..."*. *"The geometric centroid of a region can
>   be computed in the Wolfram Language using* `Centroid[reg]`.

However it doesn't work for me. Does this function still exist in Mathematica 11 or do I need to use `Needs`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it is a thin plate and so essentially 2D, you can use the density as the third dimension.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{5 <= x <= 8, 0 <= y <= 20/x^2, 0 <= z <= 2 x^2}, {x, y, z}];
RegionCentroid[reg]//Most

out = {13/2, 1/4}
```

Comment: Nice! I think this solution is valid for 3 dimension regions by adding a density function as the 4th dimension. Am I right?

Comment: I believe so...

Answer (score 11):

You can use region integrals:

```
reg=ImplicitRegion[{5<=x<=8,0<=y<=20/x^2},{x,y}];

δ[x_,y_]:=2x^2

Integrate[{x,y} δ[x,y], {x,y} ∈ reg] / Integrate[δ[x,y], {x,y} ∈ reg]
```

> {13/2, 1/4}